# Unity3D : Creating & Sharing light-baked levels without updating the game

Tags: unity, level-design, levels, lightmap

I want to give myself freedom to add more levels after releasing the game. For creating levels I broke down structure and created a tilemap like a structure. here's an example :

[image]

I will add them up to create a level and send it to server from where I can download the JSON in game and read it at run time to place things around. The problem is I want to also use Global Illumination. What I can do is send lightmap data with created level to server and download and use it for lighting after generating level. But what If my map is huge?? I don't want to have lightmap size. The other thing I can do is create light baked prefabs, suggested by this article, https://unity3d.com/how-to/light-baked-prefabs-on-mobile. But every single object has to be attached to a surface and baked because of shadows. Is there a better approach?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you show us an example of what your level with light baking should look like? There might be cheap ways to fake the effect for the specific look you need.

Comment: Typical practice with lightmapping is to bake the shadows of any static items, and use dynamic shadows for anything that can move. So your level can be tiled (assuming no shadows extend past the bounds of each tile) and then you can instance in the dynamic objects at runtime. I'd also examine your file sizes, you may find that the level files aren't so large and can be served intact rather than constructed at runtime.

Comment: @DMGregory Added an example picture.

Comment: @Ruadhan2300  Ahh. That's awesome. I didn't see that. It does have a small size. Let me try to create a huge level and then see the size of both lightmap and level. It will save a lot of work If I could managed to get both of them under 400kb. Thanks dude.

Comment: @Ankitsinghkushwah Sometimes the most direct solution is the simplest :)